# SQLで特定の項目が同一かつ、別の項目が異なるデータの把握

Tags: sql

1テーブルに対して特定の項目(社員コード)が同一かつ、別の項目(お客様コード)が異なるデータがあるものを把握できるSQLを作成したいのですが上手くいくSQLが思いつきません。どういったSQLを書けば実現できますでしょうか
テーブルのデータ
例

```
Aテーブル
お客様コード 社員コード
   12         1
   13         2
   14         1
   15         2
   16         3
```

~

Comment: 例の場合の、期待する出力も併記してもらえると回答しやすいです。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

要件がちょっと解り難いのですが、こういう事でしょうか？

```
select 社員コード
from A
group by 社員コード
having count(distinct お客様コード) > 1
```

この場合、例に対する出力は下記のようになります。

```
社員コード
1
2
```